# How to pass arguments to tcl script in Vivado GUI tcl console

Tags: tcl, vivado

I am trying to execute a tcl script in Vivado GUI Tcl Console and my script takes an argument to decide which type of run (synth, impl, bitgen etc.) has to be configured.
I know that, using `-tclargs` one could pass arguments if the script is executed in Vivado command-line mode. Something like:

```
vivado -mode batch -source <filename> -tclargs <arguments>
```

I tried the same in Vivado gui mode and got an error.

```
ERROR: [Common 17-170] Unknown option '-tclargs', please type 'source -help' for usage info.
```

Running `'source -help'`:

```
Syntax: 
source  [-encoding <arg>] [-notrace] [-quiet] [-verbose] <file>

Usage: 
  Name         Description
  ------------------------
  [-encoding]  specify the encoding of the data stored in filename
  [-notrace]   disable tracing of sourced commands
  [-quiet]     Ignore command errors
  [-verbose]   Suspend message limits during command execution
  <file>       script to source
```

By looking at `-help` I am getting a feeling that it is not possible to do so. Also, I can't find any documents for doing so. I would like to know if there is any way of achieving this.

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to just set argv and argc before calling source?

Comment: @haggai_e, thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `source` command doesn't set up the arguments; it's more like C's `#include` than anything else really. Because of that, if the script that you are `source`ing expects `argv` and `argc` to be set — as if the script was run as a program — then you should just `set` them before the `source`. They are ordinary variables as far as Tcl's concerned; they just happen to be set up by default.

You might also need to set `argv0` to the script. Some programs expect that when running in non-interactive mode.

```
set argv [list "a b c" foo bar 123]
set argc [llength $argv]
set argv0 theScript.tcl
source $argv0
```